# How to order a list depending on what the words start with?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to print the word in the beginning of the list if it starts with the letters e and s, and print at the end if it starts with any other letter. 
For example:
input: band fan egg laura sand

output: sand egg band fan laura

What should I do to make it work? This is what I've done so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class list {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    LinkedList<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
    String s = scan.next();
    final String[] letters = {"s", "S", "e", "E"};
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      if (s.startsWith(letters[i])) {
        names.addFirst(s);
      } else {
        names.addLast(s);
      }
      for (int f = 0; f < names.size(); f++) System.out.print(names.get(f) + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a coherent question that I could find

Comment: Please clarify your requirements and show some example orderings.  If you don't, your question is likely to attract downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Which comes first, `e` or `s`?  Does upper/lower case matter? What order should the remaining entries (not `e` or `s`) be sorted in?  Lots of unspecified details make an answer difficult.  This is basic requirements gathering that you must do before tackling a problem.

Comment: Also, the code you have does not sort at all so I would start by something that sorts in whaterver order, and improve from there.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are some mistakes you made

- s is the whole list the user typed in
- you put the for-loop that prints the answer in the letter-reading loop
- do println() instead of print()

But, It's ok, we all make mistakes, and you sometimes need help.
So, I'd fix it so it's like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class list {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

LinkedList<String> names = new LinkedList<>();
String s = scan.nextLine();
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
String k = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == " ".charAt(0)) {
        l.add(k);
        k="";
    } else {
        k = k + s.charAt(i);
    }
}
final String[] letters = {"s", "S", "e", "E"};
for (String ss : l) {
    boolean isfalse = true;
  for (String letter : letters) {
      if (ss.startsWith(letter)) {
          names.addFirst(ss);
          isfalse = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  if (isfalse) {
      names.addLast(ss);
  }
}
  for (String name : names) {
      System.out.println(name);
  }}}
```

I hope this helped you! :)

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot! :)

Comment: Nice code share and tips.